# How to make time reminder in view using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My code :

```
{{\Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffForHumans(Carbon\Carbon::parse($sub->created_at))}}
```

Output : 1 hour after

I want to make a time reminder on my website but the result is not what I want. I want the output of the code like this: ( 1 hour more) or if possible I want it like this: ( 1 hour 30 minutes 25 seconds more ) can you help me?. I've been trying all day but it didn't work

Comment: Just swap the parameters, and Carbon will automatically show "1 hour *until*".

Comment: can you explain in more detail please?

Comment: Again, just swap it around. `Carbon::parse($sub->created_at)->diffForHumans(Carbon::now())`

Comment: As far breaking it down, you can pass in the number of parts either as the 4th parameter, or as an array. See https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff - `You may pass a number between 1 and 6 as a 4th parameter to get the difference in multiple parts (more precise diff) : diffForHumans($other, CarbonInterface::DIFF_RELATIVE_AUTO, false, 4).`

Comment: @ceejayoz I've tried it but the result is the same

Comment: @Tomoro Then it's time to start digging on the (excellent) Carbon docs. https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: I don't see a way to change before/after to something you specify, however.  There is `DIFF_RELATIVE_TO_NOW`, which does ago/from now

Comment: The easiest way is `{{ str_replace('after','more',$sub->created_at) }}` **Note** : `$sub->created_at` is already a carbon instance, you don't need to parse it again